# What is this cactus with flat pads and spines growing in small patches?

Tags: identification, cactus, succulents

I was given a cutting of a friend's cactus. It is growing in his front yard but he does not know much about it.  His cacti are green and segmented some with red bulbs on top. I believe the red bulbs were fruit, not unopened flowers.  All segments of the cactus (like the segment I was given as a cutting) have patches thick with spines which would stick to skin on touch as you can see in the picture:

[image]

Most of the pads were larger than the one pictured. It is only about 3 inches in diameter, while some of the pads were much larger than that. But they all generally had the same shape, generally flat with a slight curve, rounded, and segmented. His plants stood a little more than 3 feet off of the ground at max height.

I am located on central part of the east coast (USA) near the ocean.

Comment: Definitely an *Opuntia* species, still trying to find out which one.

Comment: Those fruit are edible and excellent by the way! They taste like a cross between watermelon and bubblegum. The seeds within are not harmful, but generally considered inedible. I assume since you have a cutting that you intend to root it?

Comment: @Fondor1 Yes I intend to root it and hopefully have it grow into a larger cactus

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like exactly like the Opuntia Humifusa to me.
They grow on the Eastern Seaboard and all the way out to Montana.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opuntia_humifusa